Probability a simple symmetric random walk doesn’t return to zero in $N$ steps
Let $S_n$ be a simple symmetric random walk started at $S_0 = 0$. It’s a standard exercise to compute the probability that $S_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in \{1, \cdots, N\}$.
Proposition: $\mathbb{P}[S_n \neq 0 \text{ for all } n \in \{1, \cdots, N\}] = {N’ \choose N’/2} 2^{-N’}$, where $N’$ is the largest even number less than or equal to $N$.
The standard proof of this fact argues via the ballot theorem, and summing over all the possible numbers of positive steps.
I’m wondering if there is a more slick proof of this proposition. Using the ballot theorem, in some sense, replaces this Martingale problem with a sequence of “sampling without replacement” problems. In general, I feel like Martingales are easier to work with, so there should be a more direct proof. For example, if we use optional stopping or Wald’s identity, we could solve the problem by considering the distribution of final values for the random walk when we know we never hit zero, but that seems like an equally difficult problem to reason about.
Does anyone know a slick proof of this proposition?

The result for odd $N$ is an immediate consequence of the result for even $N$ as you cannot be at $0$ after an odd number of steps of $\pm 1$, so let's suppose $N$ is even.
We can call $R_N$ the event of the first return to $0$ being after exactly $N$ steps (with a probability $\mathbb P(R_N)={N \choose N/2} \frac{1}{(N-1)2^N}$ related to Catalan numbers), and $Q_N$ the event of no return to $0$ in $N$ steps.
The hypothesis is $\mathbb P(Q_N)={N \choose  N/2} \frac{1}{2^N}$, which is correct for $N=0$ and $N=2$.  It is also $\mathbb P(S_N=0)$.
Then $\mathbb P(Q_{N+2})= \mathbb P(Q_{N}) - \mathbb P(R_{N+2}) = {N \choose N/2} \frac{1}{2^N} - {N+2 \choose (N+2)/2} \frac{1}{(N+1)2^{N+2}} = {N+2 \choose (N+2)/2} \frac{1}{2^{N+2}}$ and this proves the hypothesis by induction.

Is the odd-$N$ result really an immediate consequence of the even-$N$ result? If $N$ is odd, the first step is WLOG an up-step, and the the remaining $N-1$ steps must stay at or above level $1$. So, you need to show the probability that $N-1$ random steps will stay at or above their starting level is $2^{N-1}\binom{N-1}{(N-1)/2}$. I think you need to explain how this follows from the "never return to zero" result.

@MikeEarnest.  $S_n$ always has the same parity as $n$. This means that if $N$ is odd $(\text{ and }N' = N-1)$ then $S_N \not =0$, so the probability that $S_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in {1,2, \cdots, N',N}$ must be equal to the probability that $S_n \neq 0$ for all $n \in {1,2, \cdots, N'}$.

For any integer $n$, let

$E_n$ be the set of walks of length $2n$ that end at zero.
$D_n$ be the set of walks of length $2n$ which never return to zero.
$G_n$ be the set of walks of length $2n$ which are always nonnegative.

It is obvious that $|E_n|=\binom{2n}n$. Much less obviously, we also have $|D_n|=|G_n|=\binom{2n}n$. These two results easily imply your result as a corollary. These results are well-known; the particular proof is sketched as an exercise in Feller's An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications, problem III.10.7. Feller attributes the solution to E. Nelson.

When $N$ is even, the probability of never returning to zero is $|D_{N/2}|\cdot 2^{-N}$, by definition of $D_{N/2}$.

When $N$ is odd, say the the first step of the walk is an up-step, WLOG. In order to never return to zero, the remaining $N-1$ steps must be a walk which stays at or above its starting level. By definition of $|G_{(N-1)/2}|$, the probability of success is $|G_{(N-1)/2}|\cdot 2^{-(N-1)}=|G_{N'/2}|\cdot 2^{-N'}$.


Proof that $|E_n|=|G_n|$.
Given a walk $w\in E_n$, define the "initial segment" of $w$ to be the part that ends when $w$ reaches its minimum value. We then obtain a walk $w'$ from $w$ by reversing the direction and order of the initial segment of $w$, and then placing it at the end of $w$. The resulting $w'$ can be seen to be in $G_n$.
Conversely, given a walk $w'\in G_n$, definite its "final segment" to be everything starting from the last time $w'$ reaches half of its final value. If you take the final segment of $w'$, reverse the directions of all steps, reverse the order of final steps, and finally move that segment to the beginning, then you recover $w$. This shows the correspondence $w\mapsto w'$ is bijective, proving $|E_n|=|G_n|$.
Proof that $E_n=D_n$.
Given a walk $w\in E_n$, define its "initial segment" as follows:

If $w$ starts with an up-step, the initial segment ends when $w$ first reaches its maximum value.

If $w$ starts with a down-step, the initial segment ends when $w$ first reaches its minimum value.


Let $w'$ be obtained from $w$ by negating all steps in the initial segment of $w$ (down becomes up, and vice versa), and then reversing the initial segment. Then $w'\in D_n$. This correspondence $w\mapsto w'$ is bijective, with the following inverse map. Given $w'\in D_n$, we obtain the corresponding $w$ by reversing and negating the "initial segment" of $w'$, where the initial segment is defined like this:

If $w'$ starts with an up-step, the initial segment ends when $w$ last reaches half its final value with an up step.

If $w'$ starts with a down-step, the initial segment ends when $w$ last reaches half its final value with a down step.


